# R: print dataframe rows one by one in a good looking way

Tags: r, printing, console

I run a loop and every round a progress report should be printed to the console. Currently this is my printing code:

```
  estimationReportPrint=estimationReport
  if(iterationIdx>1){names(estimationReportPrint)=NULL}
  print(tail(estimationReportPrint,1))
```

(So at iteration 1 the last row is printed with headers and at higher iterations the last row is printed without headers.)

However, the result is quite ugly. (Blank rows and unequal column widths.)

[image]

I would of course like it to look like this:

[image]

Any suggestions?
(Please remember I only print one row at a time!)

Comment: This comes close, but isn't perfect. `xy1` is a data.frame. `for (i in 1:5) {do.call(cat, xy1[i, ]); cat("\n")}`

Comment: Hey, at least you took away the blank rows which is half of the problem. Thanks! I will remember if I continue to mess around with this.

Comment: May I know why you replied in the comments instead of using the reply button? You gave a useful solution for (half of) my problem.

Comment: if someone is giving a quick and dirty fix that might not completely solve your question, they will frequently just leave a comment with the relevant code to help you along. Since it's not a complete answer, it's not really a good idea to submit as an Answer.

Comment: What he/she said. :)